# Remove button removes all the dynamically created fileds using the data from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my view with form where my data is dynamically adding fields using foreach:-

```
<div class="form-body1">
  <div class="col-md-4">        
   <?php if(!empty($content['Items']))
      { 
        $item = json_decode($content['Items'],true);
        foreach ($item as $key => $object) 
        {  ?>
          <?php if($key ==0)
            {
              for($i=0; $i<1 ; $i++ )
              {?>
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Description</label>
                <input type="text" value = '<?php echo $object['Description'];?>'placeholder="Description" name = 'description[]' maxlength="255" class="form-control input-circle"> 
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Price</label>
                <input type="number" value = "<?php echo $object['Price'];?>" placeholder="0.00" id="i-item_price_0" name = 'usd[]' autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-circle">

            <?php}
            } 
            else
            { ?>
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Description</label>
          <input type="text" value = '<?php echo $object['Description'];?>'placeholder="Description" name = 'description[]' maxlength="255" class="form-control input-circle">
          <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Price</label>
          <input type="number" value = '<?php echo $object['Price'];?>' placeholder="0.00" id="i-item_price_0" name = 'usd[]' autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-circle">
          <button href="#" id = "remove_field" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
          <br>


            <?php }
        }
      }
      else
      { ?>
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Description</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name = 'description[]' maxlength="255" class="form-control input-circle"> <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Price</label><input type="number"  placeholder="0.00" id="i-item_price_0" name = 'usd[]' autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-circle"> 
    <?php } ?>
  </div>        
</div>
```

As you can see in my view i have taken a foreach for data from database coming in the variable $content . But i have also included the add another item field which ignites my jquery and dynamically adds fields of "description" and price along with a remove option with it.

```
<div class="form-actions">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
      <button class="btn btn-circle blue" id = 'add_item' >Add another Item</button>

       <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/invoice_invoice/create_invoice'"  class="btn btn-circle green">Create Invoice</button>
      <button type="submit" name = 'draft' value = 'draft' onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/invoice_invoice/create_invoice'" class="btn btn-circle grey-salsa btn-outline">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery that runs this whole process. When I click the remove button of my dynmaically added fields with the data coming from database ,all the fields that are created gets removed.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 9; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".form-body1"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $("#add_item"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initial text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

        $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-4"><label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Description</label><input type="text" name = "description[]" placeholder="Description" maxlength="255" class="form-control input-circle" required> <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Price</label> <input type="text" name = "usd[]" placeholder="0.00" id="i-item_price_0" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-circle" required><button href="#" id = "remove_field" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></div>'); //add input box

    }
    else{ alert('Maximum 9 Items!');}
});

$(wrapper).on("click","#remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: This: `<button href="#" id = "remove_field"` will give all your buttons the same ID. ID's _must_ be unique within a HTML document. This goes for all the elements in your loop that has a hard coded ID.

Comment: Yea i have figured that out . But i dont know how could i assign different id's if they are created dynamically

Comment: You don't need to. Assign a class and create the click event based on that instead. Like: `<button href="#" class="remove_field"...` and then `$(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_field', ....)`

Comment: You should also indent your code (the html) properly since you're using a lot of nested loops and if-statements. It's pretty hard to see the flow and what code belongs to what block.

Comment: As a general note: people don't usually answer when you post so much *specific* code that is ill-formatted. Please reduce your question down to a minimal and verifiable example.

Comment: Okay sir , I will consider that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same `id` for multiple elements, instead use `class`. Change:

`<button href="#" id = "remove_field" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>`

To:

`<button href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove_field">Remove</button>`

Then select the class instead of id, change:

`$(wrapper).on("click","#remove_field", function(e){});`

To:

`$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){});`

**EDIT**:

> I dont know how could i assign different id's if they are created dynamically – Bhargav Trivedi

You can use the `x` variable you defined to increment the `id`:

`<button href="#" id="remove_field_' + x + '" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>`